# fastest way to compute many small dot products

Tags: python, numpy

I have two n-by-3 blocks contiguous in memory ("n vectors of length 3") and I'd like to compute the dot product between each of the rows as fast as possible. In numpy, using [`einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) is the fastest variant to the best of my knowledge (`einsum("ij,ij->i", a, b)`).

I've compared this to the transposed variant (also contiguous in memory), i.e., two 3-by-n blocks. Here, the each of the components (`x`, `y`, `z`) form a big block in memory rather than n contiguous 3-blocks. I found that computation here can be about twice as fast:

[image]

I'm out of memory at $2^{25}$ vectors so I'd be interested in results beyond that point.

Any idea on *why* the transposed variant is so much faster at that size range?

---

Code to reproduce the plot:

```py
import numpy
import perfplot


def setup(n):
    a = numpy.random.rand(n, 3)
    b = numpy.random.rand(n, 3)
    aT = numpy.ascontiguousarray(a.T)
    bT = numpy.ascontiguousarray(b.T)
    return (a, b), (aT, bT)


perfplot.save(
    "rel.png",
    setup=setup,
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(1, 25)],
    kernels=[
        lambda data: numpy.einsum("ij, ij->i", data[0][0], data[0][1]),
        lambda data: numpy.einsum("ij, ij->j", data[1][0], data[1][1]),
    ],
    labels=["einsum", "einsum.T"],
    xlabel="len(a), len(b)",
    relative_to=1,
    flops=lambda n: n,
)
```

Comment: yesterday spent some time experimenting and went under the hood of the `einsum` implementation inside numpy on github. Man, that function is complicated.

Comment: Yes, einsum is a monster. If one can reproduce this with plain C, that'd also be great.

Comment: BTW, there's a GPU-specific library for this kind of operation -- https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cutensor/api/cutensor.html#cutensorcontraction